# graphite-web is showing Empty Nodes for Ceres Data

Tags: graphite

I am currently porting a Whisper installation over to Graphite v0.10.0

I have finished an install of Graphite to /opt/graphite and configured the carbon-daeomon.py to launch up a writer  (plaintext on 2103) and the listener (cache) on 7102

I can send in metrics using simple echo / nc and can read these stats via ceres-node-read

When I launch up graphite, it is rendering the Metrics Tree for the statistics, but no node values are showing up.. just folders.

The last folder is the statistic node, but Graphite-Web sees it as a folder.

Has anyone seen this before ? Later on I will be investigate the graphite to carbon-daemon via tcpdump, but was just hoping if anyone has seen this issue before.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set CERES_DIR in local_settings.py and DON'T add CERES_DIR to STANDARD_DIRS

after this made this change in settings.py.

```
STORAGE_FINDERS = (
    'graphite.finders.ceres.CeresFinder',
)
```

It will fix this behaviour.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @neminem, I can't comment posts, I can only add "answers"

Comment: Not having the comment priv is not sufficient reason to post non-answers as answers, that doesn't change the rules - it should, rather, encourage you to get sufficient rep to be able to comment. (That said, after the edits, it does look a lot more like an answer now, so I could have been too hasty in flagging it.)